# Speed up query with multiple EXISTS

Tags: performance, mysql-5.5, select

I've split a monolithic table with hundreds of strings into a set of generic table + strings table, split by language. Here are the creates:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `used` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `create_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `using` (`used`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=728557 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `items_translations` (
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lang_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `translation` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `untranslatable` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dupli` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `poor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`lang_code`),
  KEY `poor_idx` (`poor`),
  KEY `lang_idx` (`lang_code`),
  KEY `dupli_idx` (`dupli`),
  KEY `translation_idx` (`translation`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I removed anything not really necessary from the tables, but I tried to keep all the meaningful columns and the ones that are held in an index.

---

I now have to do a search where a word is written in a way, in multiple languages. It was easy the way I had before, but since now a row implies a language and a specific item, it is much harder (and slower) to do that query. I'm doing it like so right now:

```
SELECT 
    item_id, create_time, user_id
FROM
    items its
WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM items_translations
        WHERE item_id = its.item_id 
        AND lang_code = 'en' 
        AND translation LIKE 'ten%')
    AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM items_translations 
        WHERE item_id = its.item_id 
        AND lang_code = 'es' 
        AND translation LIKE 'diez%')
    AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM items_translations 
        WHERE item_id = its.item_id 
        AND lang_code = 'ca' 
        AND translation LIKE 'deu%')
    AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM items_translations 
        WHERE item_id = its.item_id 
        AND lang_code = 'fr' 
        AND translation LIKE 'dix%')
    AND EXISTS( SELECT * FROM items_translations 
        WHERE item_id = its.item_id 
        AND lang_code = 'it' 
        AND translation LIKE 'dieci%');
```

It is slow, about 5 to 20 seconds (depending on the search or how busy the server is).

When I check the explain plan, well...

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table              | type   | possible_keys                    | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | its                | ALL    | NULL                             | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                 | 599762 | Using where |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | items_translations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,lang_idx,translation_idx | PRIMARY | 24      | db.its.item_id,const |      1 | Using where |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | items_translations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,lang_idx,translation_idx | PRIMARY | 24      | db.its.item_id,const |      1 | Using where |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | items_translations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,lang_idx,translation_idx | PRIMARY | 24      | db.its.item_id,const |      1 | Using where |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | items_translations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,lang_idx,translation_idx | PRIMARY | 24      | db.its.item_id,const |      1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | items_translations | eq_ref | PRIMARY,lang_idx,translation_idx | PRIMARY | 24      | db.its.item_id,const |      1 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------+-------------+
```

I lose the indexation on the first select, so the bottleneck seems there. Is there a way to speed up this kind of query?

Comment: Hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ, done. I made sure I had all the indexes done when I created the new table

Comment: I would try adding an index on `(lang_code, translation, item_id)` first. If I find time, I may post an answer with different ways to write the query (that might be using different indexes). Look for [relational-division](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22relational-division%22) as well.

Comment: By the way, `varchar(6)` with utf-8 could probably replaced with `char(2)` with ascii. 2 bytes versus potentially 19 is a small win. The same for the `translation` column. Can it be changed to acii or you ned utf-8 there? Can it be made smaller size (e.g. 5) or you need 255?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, thanks for the index, I'll try and repeat the process. About the `varchar(6)`, heh, sadly we had a `char(2)` for years... until we wanted to add languages that don't have an ISO-1 code and need more characters (either three, or even 5 if we want to stick to also locales, like es_MX for Mexican)

Comment: OK then. But you could still use ascii, not utf-8, for these codes. So the `lang-code` is ascii but the `translation` uses utf-8.